# How to permutate words for an input

Tags: groovy

I want to permute the words of a keyboard input and to compare with the elements of a list. How I can do it using groovy?

Comment: Please give some details. Also this seems like something you can solve on your own. There isn't any real question you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Right, having a guess at what you mean, this lets you enter a line of text.  The line of text is split into words, and then it prints out;

1. entered words that are found in the internal list
2. entered words that are not in the internal list
3. words in the internal list that were not entered

Here's the code:

```
def words = [ 'tim', 'yates' ]

def enteredWords = System.console()?.readLine( 'Enter some words: ' ).tokenize()

def intersection = words.intersect( enteredWords )
def nonintersection = enteredWords - intersection
def missing = words - enteredWords

println "Words you entered that are in my list: $intersection"
println "Words you entered that are not in my list: $nonintersection"
println "Words you missed from my list: $missing"
```

So, for the input `This is typed by tim`, the output is:

```
Words you entered that are in my list: [tim]
Words you entered that are not in my list: [This, is, typed, by]
Words you missed from my list: [yates]
```